# Let H be a Hilbert space. Suppose X a subset of H.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, connectedness, path-connected

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Suppose $X$ a subset of $H$.

If $X$ is connected and compact then $X$ is connected by path?

Comment: @halrankard in the case of \(\mathbb{R}^2\) is compact?

Comment: If you are asking about the answers below then, yes, the set $X$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ since it is closed and bounded.

Comment: I talking about $X=(\sin(1/x),x)$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but let me try to clarify. Let $Y$ be the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ over $(0,1]$. So $Y=\{(x,\sin(1/x)):x\in (0,1]\}$. This set  is not compact. The set $X$ below is the **closure** of $Y$ *which is compact*. It is also connected and not path connected.

Comment: Welcome to Math.StackExchange! To help people who would like to answer, you should provide more context for your question (Is it an exercise for a course? Is it a sub-problem of a bigger problem?). More importantly you should always include any attempts or ideas you've had, in general the community prefers questions where it's clear that the asker has actually tried something. For more information, please see the helpful community post [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 1):

Not true even for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $G$ is a graph of $y=\sin 1/x$, $0<x\leq 1$, regarded as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $X$ being a closure of the the graph $G$ is compact, connected, but not path connected. Is you draw a picture you will see it is not path connected. Proving it is connected is standard.

Comment: I think that this set is not compact, otherwise it should be locally compact, no?

Comment: That set $X$ is indeed compact, because $X$ is the closure of the bounded set $G$.

Answer (score 1):

This fails in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $X$ be the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ for $x\in (0,1]$, together with the segment $\{0\}\times[-1,1]$. Then $X$ is connected but not path connected.

For proofs see Theorem 3.7 and Corollary 3.8 of these notes:

https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/topology/connnotpathconn.pdf

**Edit:** Note that the set $X$ is precisely the *closure* of the graph of $y=\sin(1/x)$ over $(0,1]$. So this answer is the same as Piotr Hajlasz's (which came in just before mine, but I don't know if that means I should delete. )

Comment: I understood. It is because i need to construct a path joining two points in $X$. Thank you